# Open .pdf file in a new tab

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my form I have a ddl that user can choose between some pdf files.
 I want to pass the ID of the user's selection (it's contains the full path of the pdf) to an window.open command.

```
//This is the div that contains the data
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <label asp-for="FDescr" class="control-label">File</label>
                    <select asp-for="FCodeID" class="form-control"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "FCodeID", "FDescr"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>

//This is where I load the data in the #FCodeID ddl
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MCodeID").on("change", function () {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Materials/GetFiles";
                var ddlsource = "#MCodeID";
                var items = "<option value='0'>--Select File--</option>";
                $("#FCodeID").html(items);
                var items = " ";
                $.getJSON(url, { MCodeID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    $("#FCodeID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, file) {
                        if (file.value.includes("in Use"))
                            items += "<option value='" + file.value + "'" + "style='background-color:orange;'>" + file.text + "</option>";
                        else
                            items += "<option value='" + file.value + "'>" + file.text;
                    });
                    $("#FCodeID").html(items);
                });
            })
        })
    </script>

//This is what I'm trying to accomplish
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#FCodeID").on ("change", function () {
                var url= "#FCodeID";
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            })
        })
    </script>
```

I want on the window.open() to open a new tab with the actual path of my file. 
 e.x 192.168.1.1/MyFiles/MyPDF.pdf
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `#FCodeID` is clearly not a valid URL, it's the ID of an element. Did you mean to get the selected value from that element? Does that contain a URL? Try `var url = this.value;` instead

Comment: `var url= "#FCodeID";` What does that do now?

Comment: in the #FCodeID I store the full path+filename of the user's selection. #FCodeID ddl contains {"disabled":false,"group":null,"selected":false,"text":"24113.03 - filename.pdf - 0,52 MB","value":"\\\\192.168.1.191\\MyFiles\\filename.pdf "}. 
I want to use the value as the url. Hope now I'm more clear.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @ADyson yes it works, Thanks. Now I have to solve the "Not allowed to load local resource:" error I get in the output box.

Comment: You need to specify a proper URL with http:// and using forward slashes not backslashes. Currently you're specifying a file path, not a URL. If you want to show something on a web page, it must be accessible via a webserver

Comment: How can I change my file path to a URL? Is that possible?

Comment: yes, if your file is accessible via your webserver. Do you understand how to configure your webserver? Do you use IIS, or Apache, or something else?

Comment: Right now I run my project from localhost but eventually I publish it to an IIS. But to be clear the project or the files must be on a webserver? Because the file are in a file server on our premises

Comment: Well depending on where the IIS server is located that might not be a problem. If the IIS server can locate those files on the network then it can serve them over the web to others. Will you be hosting your IIS on premises as well?

Comment: Yes the IIS will be on premises too. The File server is on location A and the IIS on the location B but the 2 points are communicate by VPN. So I try to publish the project and let you know.

Comment: Ok. P.s. even when you're running on localhost you still have a webserver - maybe IIS Express if you are loading the site via visual studio. It can still be configured to map your file server paths to a URL. So that gives you a way to test before publishing

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry for all my question, I'm very new to this

Comment: You can [start here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-google&ei=_63_XObkPLLzxgP5_6OwBQ&q=configure+iis+express+add+virtual+directory&oq=configure+iis+express+add+vir&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.1.0.33i22i29i30l2j33i160l2.13626.14686..15830...0.0..0.137.848.3j5......0....1.........0i71j0i67j0j0i22i30.rNW42GoTBrE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by @ADyson

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FCodeID").on ("change", function () {
      var url = "../MaterialsFiles" + this.value;;
      window.open(url, '_blank');
    })
  })
</script>
```

Also, I change the .value string in my JsonResult like this:

```cs
public JsonResult GetFiles(string MCodeID)
{
    List<Files> filelist = new List<Files>();
    //Searching Files in //192.168.1.191
    string path = @"path to file srv";
    string searchPattern = MCodeID + "*";
    DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach (var file in fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var changeSlash = file.FullName.Replace('\\', '/');
        var filepath = changeSlash.Replace("path to file srv", "");
        filelist.Add(new Files
        {
            FCodeID = filepath,
            FDescr = file.Name + " - " + Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(file.Length) / (1024 * 1024)), 2) + " MB",
        });
        }
    filelist.Insert(0, new Files { FCodeID = "0", FDescr = "--Select File--" });
    return Json(new SelectList(filelist, "FCodeID", "FDescr"));
}
```

Finally I add a new Virtual like:

```
<site name="MaterialProject" id="2">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path to solution local file" />
    <virtualDirectory path="/MaterialsFiles" physicalPath="path to file srv" />
  </application>
</site>
```